# Restcomm Media Player fail to paly file on S3 with error 312

Tags: restcomm

I have a file on AWS S3 that is public:
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/voxist-greetings/33631222504/33651291239_95113eed-386b-4264-a4cf-46182faae125COUCOU1.wav

Now when RVD try to play it I get:
INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.interpreter.VoiceInterpreter] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8586) MediaGroupResponse, succeeded: false  jain.protocol.ip.mgcp.JainIPMgcpException: The IVR request failed with the following error code 312

I don't know why... The same file used to work with another name.

Thanks for any hint on how to debug this.

Comment: Hi, what version of Restcomm you run?

Comment: Version is: v7.7.0-SNAPSHOT with diversion header modification (github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/pull/1201). – karel 1 hour ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to happen on Media Server side. More specifically, it seems the file cannot be opened for some reason.

Relevant code line can be found [here](https://github.com/RestComm/mediaserver/blob/master/controls/mgcp/src/main/java/org/mobicents/media/server/mgcp/pkg/au/Play.java#L162).

Can you please take a tcpdump and share it, so we can see the MGCP Play request?

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example:

[image]

The 200 OK simply indicates that the MGCP **transaction** completed successfully. Now we need to dissect the notification (NTFY) sent from Media Server to RestComm, mainly the ObservedEvents parameter.

If you look at the picture, you will see the event triggered is an OperationFailed (of) with ReturnCode (rc) equal to 312, which is an error.
Relevant link to specs can be found [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2897#page-15).

To summarise, Media Server receives the request to play the file (in this case a cached version of it) but if fails to open the URL for some reason.

Is the URL reachable from Media Server side?

Comment: I looked at the tcpdump and I think the issue is with the cache...
I wonder if even if RVD said "Message played, path: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/voxist-greetings/33631222504/33651291239_76400402-1e17-4c9f-aaa5-29cbfd51b491.wav" in fact MGCP used a cache version that is corrupted (frame 131 I have: https://X.X.X.X:443/restcomm/cache/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/4d278f0dc476656e4e3e4244957c3878d0b49b587c4706267bc71a8615dfe99b.wav it=1) ?
But still it is weird that it said success in the tcpdump but we get hangup...

Comment: which version of RestComm are you using karel?

Comment: Indeed I have a rc=312 error !
For the cache, I am not sure how it works and how Restcomm use it... In fact, I would prefer not having this cache! My RVD make a request and it should use the file provided in the request not a cached file. In case of error getting the remote file it should give an error that I can catch at =rvd level to triger another scenario.

Comment: Version is: v7.7.0-SNAPSHOT with diversion header modification (https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/pull/1201).

Comment: @karel I'm not sure but I believe RestComm always tries to cache files by default. If you wish to make this behaviour optional, then open a feature request on https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect